# javascript web3.js library error - TypeError: Web3 is not a function

Tags: javascript, web3js

I'm trying to make web3.js library working, however I'm still getting errors. The one I can't deal with is:

```
var require=(
   function(){
       function t(e,n,r){......}
           (                         // the line 21
           {........},{},["Web3"]    // Web3 in question
           )("Web3")
   }
);
```

> line 21: TypeError: Web3 is not a function.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Add web3 in the js

```
<script src="./web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import web3. See 'Installation' here: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js